# How do you link Google Big Query to Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have a question, I want to link Big Query to Google Sheets. However, I don't have this option in Google Sheets:
Menu bar> Data> Data connectors> Connect to Big Query!
How do you get this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9702507):

> To access BigQuery data in Google Sheets, you need to meet all of the following requirements.
>
> - Access to the Google Cloud platform.
> - An Enterprise account
> - BigQuery access
> - A project with billing setup in BigQuery

Visit the documentation to have a detailed explanation of each point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already know the documentation page, but this Enterprise Plus or G Suite Enterprise for Education account is only for companies or organizations. Since I am a private user, I don't know which of these options I can choose, which are listed here: https://support.google.com/a/topic/4425947?&ref_topic=29157. If you could possibly help me with that, I would be very grateful.

Comment: The simplest and cheapest account that gives you access to Connected Sheets is Enterprise Essentials. You can sign up for it: https://workspace.google.com/pricing.html

Comment: Aww thank you too much, you helped me a lot!

Comment: Glad to help! For documentation purposes if you can, please accept the answer (✓) that's been helpful to you - it helps other people that have the same issue in the future find the solution too :)